# Inserting new Table/Matrix dialog in 12.2 does not work

Tags: matrix, user-interface

After upgrading to 12.2 on a Linux machine, Insert->Table/Matrix->New is without any effect, i.e. the popup dialog just disappears and no table a/o matrix is inserted.

Any idea or help would be most welcome.

Comment: Not an issue on my mac in V12.2.  Might be limited to Linux.

Comment: I always use Ctrl-, and Ctrl-Enter to insert matrices. Perhaps this is a suitable workaround for you until you find a proper solution.

Comment: I'm having the same problem under Linux

Comment: Just to add: For me, this is an issue with **12.2 only**. @mikado If you have been using previous versions, did this occur to you on previous versions also, or only in 12.2?

Comment: @Mark I only tried it in response to your question. I don't have access to earlier versions.

Comment: This is exactly how it works witth my 12.2 on Linux machine.